# Качество картинки

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, изображения, адаптивность

Есть картинка 320x200. Я размещаю ее в блоке шириной 260 пикселей, высота картинки уменьшается пропорционально до 162,5, но экран не может отображать не полное количество пикселей. Я замечаю, что качество картинки хуже, чем когда она была в блоке шириной 320 пикселей. Нужен совет.

Comment: Перерисуйте картинку под 260 пикселей, что тут ещё можно советовать-то

Comment: проблема в том что блок меняет размери на разных екранах, он не фиксированый

Comment: Тогда вам придётся смириться с потерей качества, это неизбежное следствие изменения размеров растровой картинки

Comment: Может это поможет: http://htmlbook.ru/css/image-rendering

Answer (score 0, accepted):

нашел еще одно решение. картинку задаю не через тег img, а через background. в таком случае тот конфликтный пиксель не будет отображатся вообще и картинка не будет терять качество. Для получения такого результата задаю background-size 100% и padding-top в процентах

Answer (score 1):

Возможно вам поможет элемент `<picture>`. Он позволяет отображать различные изображения для разных размеров экранов.

```html
<picture>
  <source srcset="img320x200.jpg" media="(min-width: 769px)">
  <source srcset="img200x165.jpg" media="(min-width: 450px)">
  <img src="img.jpg">
</picture>
```